# What authentication strategy to use?

Tags: node.js, authentication, openid-connect, oauth-2.0

Recently I have been reading up on OAuth2, OpenID Connect etc. But still very lost at what to use when and how to implement it. I am thinking of using NodeJS for now.

Lets say I want to create a blog service. This service will expose API's for clients to use. "Clients" include an admin CMS. I am thinking it will be nice to decouple my server and client (UI). I can change the UI without touching the server. These clients are likely going to be single page web applications.

Ok 1st question: In this example, should I be using OAuth2? Why? Isit just because I am authorizing the admin app to access by blog?

Since its SPA's, I think the right strategy is OAuth2 Implicit Flow?

For each app, eg. admin cms, I will have to generate an AppID which is passed to the auth server. No app secret is required correct?

Isit possible to use google login in this case (instead of username/password)? Does OpenID connect do this?

How do I implement all these in NodeJS? I see https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize, but I do not see how to implement the implicit flow.

I do see an unofficial example https://github.com/reneweb/oauth2orize_implicit_example/blob/master/app.js, but what I am thinking is why is sessions required? I thought one of the goals of tokens is so that server can be stateless?

I am also wondering, when should I use API key/secret authentication?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's examine your questions

1. Should I be using OAuth2? Why?

A: Well, as today the old [OpenId 2](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) authentication protocol has been marked as obsolete (November 2014) and [OpenId Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) is **an identity layer** built on top of [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/documentation/) so the real question is if is important for you and your business to know and verify the identity of your users (the authentication part). If the answer is "yes" then go for OpenId Connect otherwise you can choose any of the two, the one you feel more comfortable with.

2. Since its SPA's, I think the right strategy is OAuth2 Implicit Flow?

A: Not really. You can implement any strategy when using a SPA, some takes more work than others and greatly depends on what are you trying to accomplish. The implicit flow is the simplest but **it does not authenticate your users** since an access token is issued directly.

> When issuing an access token during the implicit grant flow, the authorization server does not authenticate the client. In some cases, the client identity can be verified via the redirection URI used to deliver the access token to the client.

I would not recommend this flow for your app (or any app that needs a decent level of security[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.16)).

If you want to keep it simple you should use [Resource Owner Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) flow with an username and password but again there is nothing that prevents you of implementing the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) flow especially if you want to allow third parties apps to use your service (which in my opinion is a winning strategy) and it will be relatively more secure than the others since it requires explicit consent from the user.

3. For each app, eg. admin cms, I will have to generate an AppID which is passed to the auth server. No app secret is required correct?

A: Yes that is correct but the client_secret can be used to add an extra layer of security to the token endpoint in the resource owner flow when you can't use Basic authentication, this is not required in any other flow.[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) [<sup>3</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)

> The authorization server MUST:

> - require client authentication for confidential clients or for any
>   client that was issued client credentials (or with other
>   authentication requirements),
> - authenticate the client if client authentication is included, and
> - validate the resource owner password credentials using its
>   existing password validation algorithm.

and

> Alternatively, the authorization server MAY support including the client credentials in the request-body (...) Including the client credentials in the request-body using the two parameters is NOT RECOMMENDED and SHOULD be limited to clients unable to directly utilize the HTTP Basic authentication scheme (or other password-based HTTP authentication schemes)

3. Is it possible to use google login in this case (instead of username/password)? Does OpenID connect do this?

A: Yes, is possible to use google login in which case you are just delegating the authentication and authorization job to the google servers. One of the benefits of working with an authorization server is the ability to have a single login to access other resources without having to create a local account for each of the resources you want to access.

4. How do I implement all these in NodeJS?

Well you started with the right foot. Using [oaut2horize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) is the most simple way to implement an authorization server to issue tokens. All other libraries I tested were too complicated of use and integrate with node and express (disclaimer: this is just my opinion). OAuthorize plays nicely with [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/)(both from the same author) which is a great framework to enforce the authentication and authorization with over 300+ strategies like google, facebook, github, etc. You can easily integrate google using [passport-google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google)(obsolete), [passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth) and [passport-google-plus](https://github.com/sqrrrl/passport-google-plus).

Let's go for the example

*storage.js*

```
    // An array to store our clients. You should likely store this in a
    // in-memory storage mechanism like Redis
    // you should generate one of this for any of your api consumers
    var clients = [
        {id: 'as34sHWs34'}
        // can include additional info like:
        // client_secret or password
        // redirect uri from which client calls are expected to originate
    ];
    // An array to store our tokens. Like the clients this should go in a memory storage
    var tokens = [];

    // Authorization codes storage. Those will be exchanged for tokens at the end of the flow. 
    // Should be persisted in memory as well for fast access.
    var codes = [];

    module.exports = {
        clients: clients,
        tokens: tokens,
        codes: codes
    };
```

*oauth.js*

```
    // Sample implementation of Authorization Code Grant

    var oauth2orize = require('oauth2orize');
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var storage = require('./storage');

    // Create an authorization server
    var server = oauth2orize.createServer();

    // multiple http request responses will be used in the authorization process 
    // so we need to store the client_id in the session 
    // to later restore it from storage using only the id
    server.serializeClient(function (client, done) {
        // return no error so the flow can continue and pass the client_id.
        return done(null, client.id);
    });

    // here we restore from storage the client serialized in the session 
    // to continue negotiation
    server.deserializeClient(function (id, done) {
        // return no error and pass a full client from the serialized client_id
        return done(null, _.find(clients, {id: id}));
    });

    // this is the logic that will handle step A of oauth 2 flow
    // this function will be invoked when the client try to access the authorization endpoint
    server.grant(oauth2orize.grant.code(function (client, redirectURI, user, ares, done) {
        // you should generate this code any way you want but following the spec
        // https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#appendix-A.11
        var generatedGrantCode = uid(16);
        // this is the data we store in memory to use in comparisons later in the flow
        var authCode = {code: generatedGrantCode, client_id: client.id, uri: redirectURI, user_id: user.id};

        // store the code in memory for later retrieval
        codes.push(authCode);

        // and invoke the callback with the code to send it to the client
        // this is where step B of the oauth2 flow takes place.
        // to deny access invoke an error with done(error);
        // to grant access invoke with done(null, code);
        done(null, generatedGrantCode);
    }));

    // Step C is initiated by the user-agent(eg. the browser)

    // This is step D and E of the oauth2 flow
    // where we exchange a code for a token
    server.exchange(oauth2orize.exchange.code(function (client, code, redirectURI, done) {
        var authCode = _.find(codes, {code: code});
        // if the code presented is not found return an error or false to deny access
        if (!authCode) {
            return done(false);
        }
        // if the client_id from the current request is not the same that the previous to obtain the code
        // return false to deny access
        if (client.id !== authCode.client_id) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        // if the uris from step C and E are not the same deny access
        if (redirectURI !== authCode.uri) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // generate a new token
        var generatedTokenCode = uid(256);
        var token = {token: generatedTokenCode, user_id: authCode.user_id, client_id: authCode.client_id};

        tokens.push(token);
        // end the flow in the server by returning a token to the client
        done(null, token);
    }));

    // Sample utility function to generate tokens and grant codes. 
    // Taken from oauth2orize samples
    function uid(len) {
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        var buf = []
            , chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
            , charlen = chars.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            buf.push(chars[getRandomInt(0, charlen - 1)]);
        }

        return buf.join('');
    }

    module.exports = server;
```

*app.js*

```
    var express = require('express');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var AuthorizationError = require('oauth2orize').AuthorizationError;
    var login = require('connect-ensure-login');
    var storage = require('./storage');
    var _ = require('lodash');

    app = express();

    var server = require('./oauthserver');

    // ... all the standard express configuration
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret code' }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.get('/oauth/authorize',
        login.ensureLoggedIn(),
        server.authorization(function(clientID, redirectURI, done) {
            var client = _.find(storage.clients, {id: clientID});
            if (client) {
                return done(null, client, redirectURI);
            } else {
                return done(new AuthorizationError('Access denied'));
            }
        }),
        function(req, res){
             res.render('dialog', { transactionID: req.oauth2.transactionID, user: req.user, client: req.oauth2.client });
        });

    app.post('/oauth/authorize/decision',
        login.ensureLoggedIn(),
        server.decision()
    );

    app.post('/oauth/token',
        passport.authenticate(['basic', 'oauth2-client-password'], { session: false }),
        server.token(),
        server.errorHandler()
    );
```

6. (...) but what I am thinking is why is sessions required? I thought one of the goals of tokens is so that server can be stateless?

> When a client redirects a user to user authorization endpoint, an authorization transaction is initiated. To complete the transaction, the user must authenticate and approve the authorization request.  Because this may involve multiple HTTP request/response exchanges, the transaction is stored in the session.

Well yes, but the session is used for the token negotiation process. Later you enforce authorization sending the token in an Authorization header to authorize each request using the obtained token.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer. I do have a few questions. "` passport.authenticate(['basic', 'oauth2-client-password'])`": In many examples a string is passed in this case its an array. Why? Is it wrong to just use '`oauth2-client-password`'? Also if I want to allow login with Google, I will replace this with `passport-google-oauth`? But where is the code to link the id token or otherwise to the app user? Is it because this is not a requirement of OAuth?

Comment: Also regarding security of implicit grant/flow. Its less secure because tokens are stored on client side? Are tokens not passed to client with other methods? The reason why its less secure is theres no need to validate the client secret? But is this really so? A hacker can still act as a client to call the server to request a token?

Comment: The `passport.authenticate` method returns a middleware function and the syntax is `passport.authenticate('strategy')` or `passport.authenticate(['strategy1', 'strategy2'])`. They authenticate your requests in the same order they were defined, the first is [basic](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http) and the second [client credentials](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2-client-password). See https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/master/examples/all-grants/auth.js for an example of some strategies and also check their github repository

Comment: Those are applied to existing routes defined in your app (eg: `app.get`, 'app.post' or `Router.post`) because express executes middleware calls in the order they were defined. Authentication and Authorization *usually* are found at the begining of this pipeline. This means a call to `/oauth/token` will execute Basic, then Client Credentials authentication and then it will issue a token. Your other routes should be protected by a similar strategy `passport.authenticate('oauth2')` or `passport.authenticate('bearer')`. Check strategies in http://passportjs.org/docs

Comment: Oh, so basic will authenticate the user and oauth2-client-password the app. Also I think I am confused because I was thinking the authorization server and app web server are the same thing (like in the same NodeJS app in my case, since its a small app)

Comment: Can I clarify: So in the authorization code flow, SPA never gets the token. App web server will maintain sessions and hold these tokens?

Comment: Basic and client credentials will execute on the token endpoint and are used to protect this route. They can also serve to populate the `clientID` parameter in some cases. This is how passport figures which value goes there. Here is the spec refering this part http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.2.1 "Confidential clients or other clients issued client credentials MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described in Section 2.3 when making requests to the token endpoint.". Implicit grant is the only flow that does not require a token endpoint.

Comment: You can combine or make them separately, there is no difference. The authorization server and the web server respond to diferent routes so they can coexist. How you handle the tokens is up to you. Using a proxy or storing them in memory in the clients or localStorage. The authorization from this point forward happens by sending an `Authorization` header in the request to your servers with the token in the form "Authorization": "<token_type> <token>" so it really depends on which flow you choose, how your businnes works and how you implemented it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107806/discussion-between-jiew-meng-and-devconcept).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, OAuth2 is the standard way of securing APIs. I'd recommend using OpenID Connect though as it adds authentication to OAuth2's otherwise authorization-based spec. You can also get Single-Sign-On between your "clients".

> Since its SPA's, I think the right strategy is OAuth2 Implicit Flow?

De-coupling your clients and servers is a nice concept (and I'd generally do the same too) however, I'd recommend the authorization code flow instead as it doesn't expose the token to the browser. Read http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/. Use a thin server-side proxy instead to add the tokens to the request. Still, I generally avoid using any server-generated code on the client (like JSPs in java or erb/haml in rails) since it couples the client to the server too much.

> For each app, eg. admin cms, I will have to generate an AppID which is passed to the auth server. No app secret is required correct?

You'll need a client ID for implicit flow. If you use authorization code flow (recommended), you'll need both an ID and secret but the secret will be kept in the thin server-side proxy rather than a client-side only app (since it can't be secret in that case)

> Is it possible to use google login in this case (instead of username/password)? Does OpenID connect do this?

Yes. Google uses openid connect

> How do I implement all these in NodeJS? I see https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize, but I do not see how to implement the implicit flow.

A nice thing about openid connect is that (if you use another provider like google), you don't have to implement the provider yourself and you'll only need to write client code (and/or utilize client libaries). See http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ for different certified implementations. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-openidconnect for nodejs.

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-24 the Authorization Code Grant "is optimized for confidential clents". It is best to consider a Single Page Application as NOT being a confidential client because most, if not all, of its logic is implemented in javascript that runs in the browser. Therefore, I would say that the initial suggestion, by Jiew Meng, to use the Implicit Flow was the correct one.

Comment: @Przemek Implicit makes simplifications to the spec for the reason that SPA-only and native mobile clients can't keep a secret (as you say). If implicit is what one wants, sure, simplify...but know that it comes at the cost of having the token exposed to the browser and the inability to use refresh tokens for offline access. I've implemented implicit flows before and now prefer the security and feature benefits of authorization code flow (when I have the choice). I'd advocate for a think server-side proxy that keeps the token and client secret server-side while using an SPA in the browser.

Comment: I wonder is authorization code flow much more secure? Are tokens never passed to client? So its using server side sessions? Also cant a hacker act as a client to authenticate with the server like he could with implicit flow? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes. It's more secure since the token never goes through the browser. The AS sends back a "code" to the browser that is useless to anyone unless they also have the client secret (only lives on the server proxy). The server proxy uses the code (from the browser) and client secret to request tokens (all server-side). With authorization code flow, your "client" includes both the SPA + the thin server-side proxy, so the token is passed to the client--but only on the server proxy. http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#CodeFlow

Comment: @sdoxsee, so server proxy will use sessions and SPA never uses any tokens?